# Unable to re-use element objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like once I append the element object to the page, I can't re-append it to another part of the page.  Something is odd about this behavior.  Does anyone know what's causing this and how to re-append the object to another element?  I've tried copying the object to a new variable name and it still doesn't help.

Here is the code: 
(should append the object to both div's, but is only appending to the first)

```
    var $e = $("<a/>")
        .append("<span>Link</span>")
        .attr("href","#")
        .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('hi');
        });
    var $e2 = $e;
    $("div:first").append( $e );
    $("div:last").append( $e2 );
```

HTML:

```
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6R75z/

Comment: You never copied the object to a new variable name though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each object is unique, `$e2` is just a reference to the created element. you should [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the collection:

```
var $e2 = $e.clone();
```

For copying the event handlers, you can pass `true` to the `clone` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the creation in a function:

```
function newATag() {
    return $("<a/>")
        .append("<span>Link</span>")
        .attr("href","#")
        .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('hi');
        });
}

$("div:first").append( newATag() );
$("div:last").append( newATag() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You create `$("a")` dom  and append element into div first one ,then you move to second one that time it does not append first one ,In this context  you have to clone the object and used

```
 var $e = $("<a/>")
        .append("<span>Link</span>")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
    });
    var $e2 = $e;
    $("div:first").append($e);
    $("div:last").append($e2.clone(true));
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6R75z/1/)